# Laravel 5.1 - Some pages are not found on production serveur - "Page you are looking for could not be found"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, server, routes, system-administration

I have a problem with **some "routes" in my old Laravel 5.1.46 project**.

When I try to access to some routes, like `admin/exercices/creer` or `admin/exercices/1928`, I have this: *"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."*.
I can access to thoses pages when I work on the test or local serveur. But not on the production serveur.
Other routes like `admin/missions/creer` are working properly.

[image]

I tried `php artisan route:list` to compare the routes on each serveur: it's the same everywhere.
I also tried `php artisan route:cache` and `php artisan route:clear`. Nothing changed.

I can remember we changed the routes path (for example: "admin/modules/creer" became "admin/exercices/creer"). I think we did it manually, directly in the routes.php file. But it waas a long time ago and since then, it already worked properly. So I don't think it comes from that, but Idk.

I'm also not good at sysadmin, so **maybe it's more about the config of the server than code and laravel**... In this case, any idea here does it come from? I have no clue, and I might need help.

Thanks a lot for reading! And let me know if you have even a tiny idea!

Comment: Does this only affect some of the routes? or is it more like all the routes except the home route?

Comment: Just some of them!

Comment: If you do e.g. `/index.php/admin/exercices/creer` would it work? If it does then there might be conflicts between your Laravel routes and server configuration e.g. maybe the server has reserved mapping `admin` for other reasons. If you have configured the server on a central configuration file then maybe check if you can add exceptions to your own routes there

Comment: Thanks for your idea! Unfortunately, it's not working either, I still have the "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found" message.

Comment: is that a webserver 404 error or a laravel 404 error?

Comment: I think it's the laravel 404 error, because it has its design (typo & color).

Comment: did you try ```php artisan route:clear``` and then ```php artisan route:cache``` ?

Comment: I did, everything is cleared and cached successfully!

Comment: that is a `ModelNotFoundException` that is being converted to a 404 ... somewhere something is trying to retrieve a Model but failing (perhaps route model binding) ... it would seem the record you are looking for doesn't exist